# Can a transition in DFSA have a power?

Tags: logic, formal-languages, automata

The Σ is {l,r,u,d} where α ∈ Σ which denote the gamepad controllers (l = left, r = right, u = up and d = down) whilst Strings s, t, ... over Σ⋆ thus denote sequence of commands on the gamepad.

Have a question in regards to the following:

Assume the predicate **even** :: N -> B that returns **true** for all the *even* natural numbers 0, 2, 4 ... and **false** otherwise.

Design a DFSA M that only accepts the gamepad command language L = { s | s ∈ Σ* and even(lefts(s))}

My question is whether or not transitions can have a power or not, the transitions in M are for example l^n such that n is even.

Can this be done? If not what is the way to tackle such a question?

(ii) Besides that I would like to ask what is the difference between s ∈ L and s ∈ L(M)

TIA

[Actual Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCplF.png)

[ii](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqiNg.png)

Comment: What is "lefts(s)"? Did you mean the length of $s$? And what do you mean by _power_? In a standard definition of DFSA, transitions are labeled by elements of $\Sigma$ (not $\Sigma^\star$, if that is what you hope to cheat with ;) As for difference - you're supposed to design an $M$ such that $L(M)=L$, with the goal of _no_ difference.

Comment: @metamorphy Not cheat but much rather learn ;) .... my mistake I failed to say that left is one of the moves that the robot can do. i.e. left, right, up and down. as to Σ⋆ thats how it is clearly stated.
I'm just finding it difficult to label the transitions since the number of lefts (one of the transitions) must be even.

Comment: Still do not understand. Your predicate "even" is defined on natural numbers, and $s\in\Sigma^\star$ is a string. Thus "lefts(s)" must be a natural number... What is it?

Comment: @metamorphy https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCplF.png

Comment: That's the actual question

Comment: You need to answer it yourself, the picture doesn't help at all. Find the definition please.

Comment: @metamorphy The Σ is {l,r,u,d} where α ∈ Σ which denote the gamepad controllers (l = left, r = right, u = up and d = down) whilst Strings s, t, ... over
Σ⋆ thus denote sequence of commands on the gamepad. 

My only issue is my understatement, besides being unsure how to work it out, I'm more concerned if I'm understanding what's being asked of me.

Comment: When posting questions here, this is I think the crucial issue. I don't believe in the telepathic abilities of the audience to guess what you've just posted in the last comment. Please kindly fill the remaining details in (and edit your question accordingly...).

Comment: @metamorphy yup my mistake.... edited accordingly. Hoping someone can help me get on the right track!

Comment: My understanding is that $\operatorname{lefts}(s)$ is the number of $l$ letters in $s$.  Is that correct?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Yes fabio exactly that, it's just I don't know how i can represent a DFSA for it.

Comment: You don't need "powers."  Use two states to remember the parity.  Switch between those two states whenever you read an $l$.  Easy peasy,

Comment: @FabioSomenzi could you please refer me to such an example or something along these lines so that I have a better understatement? I'm week 2 into this class ;)

Comment: What textbook are you using?

Comment: @rici Mostly class notes however I'm using introduction to the theory of computation by sipser ..

Comment: @DavidVella: Look at the example in the section "Designing Finite Automaton" starting on p. 41 (2nd edition). "For example, suppose that the alphabet is { 0,1 } and that the language consists of all strings with an odd number of 1s..."

Comment: @rici Thanks a lot!! Really helped!